# Determine an orthonormal base

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine an orthonormal base $({\overrightarrow{e_{1}}}, {\overrightarrow{e_{2}}},{\overrightarrow{e_{3}}})$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ so that ${\overrightarrow{e_{1}}}$ is parallel to the line $\left\{\begin{matrix}
x=1+t\\y=1-t
\\z=1+t 
\end{matrix}\right.$ and ${\overrightarrow{e_{2}}}$ is parallel to the plane $x+y+z=1$.

My work:
${\overrightarrow{e_{1}}}=(1,-1,1)$

EDIT: Thanks for all of your comments. Did i understood this correct?

Normalize ${\overrightarrow{e_{1}}}=(1,-1,1)$.
$${\overrightarrow{e_{1}}}=\frac{(1,-1,1)}{\sqrt{(1)^2+(-1)^2+(1)^2}}=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}})$$

Normal of the plane $(1,1,1)$.
$$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}&0&\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}$$

$${\overrightarrow{e_{2}}}=\frac{\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}&0&\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}}{\sqrt{\left(-\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+\left(0\right)^2+\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}$$

$${\overrightarrow{e_{3}}}=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}&\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0&\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}&-\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}&-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: $\vec{e_1}$ should be normalized

Comment: Looks good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that you have an orthonormal system.

1. You need to normalize $\vec e_1$.
2. $\vec e_2$ should be perpendicular to both the normal to the plane (because it is parallel to the plane) and $\vec e_1$ (orthonormal system). You can use the cross product. Don't forget to normalize $\vec e_2$.
3. If $\vec e_1$ and $\vec e_2$ are perpendicular and of length $1$, $$\vec e_3=\vec e_1\times\vec e_2$$
   Note that $\vec e_3$ is already normalized.

Comment: Thank you very much!